# How can one create package for ClearQuest?

Tags: bug-tracking, clearquest

I am modifying ClearQuest database schema and I wonder is there a way to create a package for future deployment. If there isn't what are best practices for tracking and deployment of schema modifications?

Answer (score 1):

In your CQ installation path, look for this "cqload" tool.

basically...

- cqoload exportintegration - Exports specific schame versions into a text
  file
- cqload importintegration - Imports the exported text file into a CQ
  schema

What is common practice is you at least have 2 CQ environments, a Dev/QA env, and a Production env. Developers work on the Dev/QA environments (checkout/modify/checkin) until they are happy, QA verified the changes in the same environment. Then the implementor will use cqload commands to transfer the changes to the production environment.

Personally I think this workflow is retarded, as it requires so many manual process and it doesnt work properly if you have additional "Packages" upgrade or installation within CQ, e.g. UCM package, etc. Unfortunately I dont think this is gonna change anytime.